# Jquery FullCalendar change editable properties of particular event on a calendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am currently using jQuery FullCalendar to create a scheduling application. In my application I need to set editable=false only for events which is not an event created by the logged in user; whereas, the event that is created by the logged in user should have editable= true. Can any on suggest me how I could set few editable property of event in a FullCalendar as false and few events as true.

Answer (score 9):

Set the master editable property to `false`  and set the editable property of the event's that you want to be editable to true.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({        
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        editable: false, // set this false
        events: [
        {
            title: 'This must be editable',
            start: new Date('11/1/2011'),
            editable:true
        },
        {
            title: 'This is non editable',
            start: new Date('11/1/2011'),
            end: new Date('11/1/2011')
        }

        ]
    });

});
```

## http://jsfiddle.net/G6K6Y/94/

Comment: Hello, jsfiddle not work  (chromium Version 28.0.1459.0 (191590))

Answer (score 7):

I know that this question is a bit older, but could help anyone searching for this:
I've done this by two ways:
The first is setting on the event source like @TheSuperTramp did:

```
{
    title: 'This must be editable',
    start: new Date('11/1/2011'),
    editable:true
}
```

The second - the way that i prefer - is to set the default value to false and compare at the rendering if the event has the same id of the user. That way you don't "hard code" the atribute on the event:

```
editable: false,
eventRender: function(event, element) {
    if(event.userId === user.id) {
        event.editable = true;
    }
},
```