# FullCalendar Changing Editable value mid script

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, fullcalendar

I'm using Angular JS with fullCalendar and I'm trying to change the value editable of my calendar when I click on a button. It seams pretty simple but for some reason nothing is working. 

I got this code to set the value editable in the first place  :

```
 var Calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
     /*...*/
     events: events,
     editable: $scope.editable,
     droppable: true,
     allDayDefault: false,
     /*...*/
 });
```

This part seams to be OK since my `$scope.editable` is false by default and the calendar does not allows any modification.

I'm using a function in Angular JS to change the value of my `$scope.editable` value to its opposite using this function :

```
 $scope.edit = function () {
    $scope.editable = !$scope.editable;
};
```

Of course it does not change the value in FullCalendar so i'm wondering what to do. I've tried a few things, like changing the value and then rerendering or refetching events but nothings seams to works.

```
 $scope.edit = function () {
    $scope.editable = !$scope.editable;
    Calendar.fullCalendar({editable: $scope.editable});
    Calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
};
```

Any ideas ?

#### Edit

I have acheived this in the past by changing the value, destroying the calendar and then building it again, i don't think this approach is the most effective. I would like to keep my calendar the way it is and just allows edition.

Comment: Looks like after it is initinialized it will not work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18017325/jquery-full-calendar-edit-calendar-view-after-initialization

Comment: @gmdev86 yea, it looks like I might need to recreate the calendar. I'll try to work around.Thanks !

Comment: you may be able to edit at the event level. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7963122/jquery-fullcalendar-change-editable-properties-of-particular-event-on-a-calendar

Comment: @gmdev86 yea but the problem with that is that I would reach a search level of N, if I have a millions event it would take lots and lots of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I did not do enough research. I found out that since FullCalendar 2.9.0 it is possible to dynamicly change options. using `Calendar.fullCalendar('option', option, value);`
[Here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/utilities/dynamic_options/) is a full link with the complete documentation if anyone need the info.