# jQuery Fullcalendar - per event change editable event to non-editable (or vice versa)

Tags: fullcalendar

I've been playing with official Fullcalendar [CodePen](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-dragging-resizing-demo)

and can't find a way to make event non-editable (or editable).

In demo, the global option is set: `editable: true`. If I try to change this setting per event with:

```
  eventRender: function(event, element){
    event.editable=false;
    }
```

nothing changes. Events are still all editable (resizable, draggable,..) . I found this post [jquery-fullcalendar-change-editable-properties-of-particular-event-on-a-calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7963122/jquery-fullcalendar-change-editable-properties-of-particular-event-on-a-calendar)

where the suggestion is:

```
editable: false,
eventRender: function(event, element) {
    if(event.userId === user.id) {
        event.editable = true;
    }
}
```

but this doesn't work. Changing `event.editable` under `eventRender` or `eventAfterRender`, does not take any effect.
Is it possible to change this setting dynamically (per event)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an [eventDataTransform](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventDataTransform) function to check if your event has the desired user Id and then change the editable property to true.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  header: {
  left: 'prev,next today',
  center: 'title',
  right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
},
  events: 'https://fullcalendar.io/demo-events.json?overload-day',
  eventDataTransform: function(event){
  if(event.userId === user.id){
  event.editable=true;
  }
 return event;
}
});

});
```

Edit: I think the eventRender function is meant to be used to modify the element. To modify the event you should use the eventDataTransform function